# Internet Server in front of Firewall communicating to server behind firewall C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Okay so this is probably a very confusing title for this question I am sure. Hopefully I can clear up that title with the actual question.

I am putting together a website for employees to connect to that is internet facing but I want them to be able to log into the site using their Active Directory login as well as access data that will be behind a firewall that is not accessible to our internet facing sites. Someone made mention to me that I could have the site communicate with a server behind the firewall and have that server make the requests back and forth. (Sort of a check point) 
So now that the back story to this is out there, I am not really looking for how to configure the server's or the network itself but rather how would one make an API call to an Intranet server from an Internet server? They will be on the same network but one behind the firewall and the other in front of the firewall.
Would you make the call directing to the server name or IP address or what? This may be too premature of a question to be asking since I still don't have the servers setup but none-the-less it is a concern I am having and need to figure out.

This site is going to be all done in ASP.NET MVC 4

Comment: There isn't anything special you need to do in the application,  basically you configure the firewall to allow your internet server to talk to your intranet server, then just write your application normally.

Comment: Okay so even though one is on one side of the firewall and the other is on the other side since they are on the same actual network I could use the intranet address of the server behind the firewall to communicate?

Comment: It depends on your network configuration, the simplest way would be to setup some kind of port forwarding on your firewall, then your internet application would point to the address of the firewall and the firewall would handle forwarding that port to the correct server.  Or you could also setup a one way trust between the two domains.

Comment: Justin for credit to be given to you please form what you have said there as an answer instead of a comment because I believe you have answered that the best it can be answered

Comment: Certainly, just wanted to be sure I was covering what you were looking for. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to accomplish this type of a setup is via firewall and/or domain configuration.
Most recently I have seen this implemented by first creating a one way trust relationship between the external and internal domains, this will serve to allow the external application to resolve the address of the internal server by name.

Theoretically you could also accomplish this by using port forwarding on the firewall; in this configuration the external application will use the address of the firewall and the firewall will take care of sending the request to the correct server.

Once this confiugration is in place your external application should be able to communicate directly with your internal servers without any special code.